# Interpreting log-transformed ARIMA Coefficients in R

Tags: r, time-series, arima, interpretation, logarithm

I am fitting an ARIMA model to do interrupted time series analysis on cancer rates. I have log-transformed the data for fitting for stability and because this is typical with cancer rates, but I am having trouble interpreting the resulting coefficients. In particular, I can't quite make out what the pulse coefficient is telling me (I have both pulse and step exogenous regressors, but they don't overlap so there is no interaction there). The output of my model is:

```
> summary(model1b)
Series: d1b.ts 
Regression with ARIMA(0,0,0)(0,1,0)[12] errors 
Box Cox transformation: lambda= 0 

Coefficients:
        pulse     step
      -0.3183  -0.0499
s.e.   0.0207   0.0192

sigma^2 = 0.002815:  log likelihood = 37.49
AIC=-68.99   AICc=-67.79   BIC=-65.45

Training set error measures:
                    ME     RMSE       MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 0.1766183 1.311897 0.8256027 0.3813519 2.425557 0.3024403 -0.2257222
```

Thanks.